# Showing that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{x(t+1)} \left(1 + \frac{e^x}{k} \right)^{-(k+1)}dx = k^{t+1} \frac{\Gamma(k-t)\Gamma(1+t)}{\Gamma{(k+1)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gamma-function

I want to show that

$$ f(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{x(t+1)} \left(1 + \frac{e^x}{k} \right)^{-(k+1)}dx = k^{t+1} \frac{\Gamma(k-t)\Gamma(1+t)}{\Gamma{(k+1)}}$$

Here, $k,t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I have tried a few things, but none worked out. First, I noticed that the quotient with all the gamma terms can arises from the beta function with $x=k-t$, $y=1+t$, and $x+y=k+1$.  But I haven't been able to transform my integral into anything of the required form.

Next, I tried using the fact that we can write $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)$ as a double integral with limits of integration $[0,\infty)$, but that did not get me anywhere.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Shouldn't there be restrictions on $k$ and $t$ such as $k > t > -1$? Otherwise, the right hand side would not make sense when $k = t$.

Comment: Good point. There are no restrictions on $k,t$, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the change of variables $\frac{e^x}{k}=z , dx=k\frac{dz}{z}$ , the integral becomes

$$
I(k,t)=k^{t+1}\int_{\mathbb{R\geq0}}\frac{z^{t}}{(1+z)^{k+1}}
$$

which equals [a integral representation of the Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

$$
I(k,t)=k^{t+1}B(t+1,k-t)=k^{t+1}\frac{\Gamma(k-t)\Gamma(t+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)}
$$

as long as $t+1>0$ and $k-t>0$

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried this change of variables, but rejected it over a mixup I had with with what values $k,t$ should take. Thanks for clearing that up.